# Why does TableLayoutPanel put its child controls in reverse order?

Tags: c#, winforms

This problem doesn't happen for all instance but this code block:

```
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 60.99398F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 39.00602F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.pbxInspectionDisplay, 0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.gbxEggInput, 0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 57);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1182, 570);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 28;
```

At the table layout, pbxInspectionDisplay is unexpectedly located on right and gbxEggInput on left. If I replace corresponding part above with following code

```
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.gbxEggInput, 0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.pbxInspectionDisplay, 0, 0);
```

they are located in right order (pbxInspectionDisplay on left and gbxEggInput on right). As I said, in other code block, first control is located on left and second one on right. So I am trying to understand what made the difference. Can somebody explain why this happens?

Comment: You are just doing it wrong.  TLP supports *one* control per cell.  You are stuffing two controls in the cell at col=0, row=0.  What happens next is unguessable.  Well, you found out I guess.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for pointing it out. I think some change made cancelled cell assignment and I forgot about it. I need to wake up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you would want to [specify the column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he3sxc2a.aspx) in which you're adding the controls. Something like this:

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.pbxInspectionDisplay, 0, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.gbxEggInput, 1, 0);
```

Comment: Oh, well. I didn't notice that. At some point, assigned them all controls right but made some change and forgot about it. Thanks!